# why pytorch QAT is worse than PTQ?

Tags: pytorch, quantization

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/static_quantization_tutorial.html#quantization-aware-training

I am following this tutorial and PTQ seems fine with about 68%

But QAT is keep giving me 65% which is less than PTQ

```
qat_model = load_model(os.path.join(saved_model_dir, float_model_file))
qat_model.train()
qat_model.fuse_model_qat()

optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(qat_model.parameters(), lr=0.0001)
qat_model.qconfig = torch.ao.quantization.get_default_qat_qconfig('x86')

torch.ao.quantization.prepare_qat(qat_model, inplace=True)
```

```
    def fuse_model_qat(self):
        for m in self.modules():
            if type(m) == ConvBNReLU:
                torch.ao.quantization.fuse_modules_qat(m, ['0', '1', '2'], inplace=True)
            if type(m) == InvertedResidual:
                for idx in range(len(m.conv)):
                    if type(m.conv[idx]) == nn.Conv2d:
                        torch.ao.quantization.fuse_modules_qat(m.conv, [str(idx), str(idx + 1)], inplace=True)
```

This is the part for QAT using torch 2.0.1+cu117.

What I am doing wrong?

I tried eval_mode + fuse_modules, deleting fusing part, qconfig: fbgemm and a lot other but it is going nowhere.